# Conditional if and else to show different category

Tags: php, categories

I am trying to make a conditional class depending on if the class is found in the water category.  I don't know much about php but I think I am close, but still does not work.  Any help is appreciated.

```
 <?php if( has_term('water','category') ) { ?>
      <p class="some-class">all water category post</p>
 <?php  } else { ?>
      <p class="some-other-class">anything other than water category post</p>
  <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can you post the function, `has_term`? Your logic from that snip alone seems to be correct, but the function is where the code is happening

Comment: What is your expected result and what is your current result? In other words: you didn't specify what your problem is. By the way, `has_term` is a Wordpress function, is this worth mentioning in your question?

Answer (score 1):

if you are talking about [WP has_term function](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term)

```
<?php if( has_term('water','category') ) { ?>
      <p class="some-class">all water category post</p>
 <?php  } else { ?>
      <p class="some-other-class">anything other than water category post</p>
  <?php } ?>
```

your code is correct if you cant see any result make sure you are calling the correct page